# Firebasestorage "downloadURL" function is not working properly, sometimes it works randomly

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

The below swift code is written to upload an image to firebase storage. Earlier it was working fine. But now onwards it works randomly. I waited 30mins to upload an image but didn't reach to success nor even in error.

I have tried different code to upload an image. Also, search a lot to analyze the problem. But sometimes it works randomly. I am not able to identify why this is happening.

To check if the image is uploading or not, I just put an observer to check the progress of an upload task, uploading works perfectly, but it didn't reach to completion block. I tried to generate download URL too after upload task done but it also didn't reach to completion block.

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("abc").child("myImage1234")
storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (storageMetaData, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                return
            }
            if let photoUrl = url?.absoluteString {
                self.imageUpload()
            }
        })
    }
})
```

I am really stuck at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code into a project and ran it 10 times. Worked perfectly each time. It looks like you maybe running an older version of firebase and/or Swift and if so, update to the latest version. Otherwise, the problem lies outside that code -perhaps your *imageData* var is not be populated correctly or it could be nil. Maybe a check for nil on that code may reveal something.

Comment: Firebase version update to 5.15.0 resolved this issue. Thanks for the help